# How to saveAndFlush data in @OneToMany relation using JpaRepository?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a table Post which has a @OneToMany Relation with Rating:

```
class Post {
  @OneToMany
  List<Rating> rating;
}
```

how should i save a new rating, without reading the precious ratings?

Comment: Do you have a bi-directional relationship?

Comment: yes, i have a bi-directional relationship between rating and post.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Repository` for `Rating` entity and save only rating

```
public interface RatingRepository extends JpaRepository<Rating, Long> {
}
```

and after inject this repository in your bean and call `ratingRepository.save()`

```
Rating rating = new Rating();
rating.setPost(post);
//...
ratingRepository.save(rating);
```

Comment: While this might be correct, it's important to give an example or some details on how to do what you suggested.